# Query Path to SQL Server Log Files (SSRS / SSAS)

Tags: t-sql, logging, reporting-services, ssas

I need to write a tsql script / procedure, that reads from the SSRS / SSAS / MSSQL Logs. 
So fare getting the location of the SQL Errorlog ist easy (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName') ).

What about the Location for SSRS / SSAS? The script will be executed on many different Servers and I know, that most of them don't use the default location for their SQL Server Instances (i.e. C:\Program Files....). Is there any way to get this paths in tsql?

Cheers
Kim

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way. Don't know if that is the best way, but it's fast and works on all my instances. Below code for the SSRS Path. SSAS works similarly.

```
DECLARE @InstanceName [nvarchar] (128)
,@SSRSInstanceName [nvarchar] (128)
,@RegPathSSRS [nvarchar] (256)
,@DirPathSSRS [nvarchar] (256)

SET @InstanceName = COALESCE(CONVERT([nvarchar](100), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')), 'MSSQLSERVER');

IF @InstanceName != 'MSSQLSERVER'
BEGIN
    SET @InstanceName = @InstanceName
END

EXEC [master]..[xp_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    ,N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS'
    ,@InstanceName
    ,@SSRSInstanceName OUTPUT;

SET @RegPathSSRS = N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\'+@SSRSInstanceName+'\Setup';
    EXEC [master]..[xp_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    ,@RegPathSSRS
    ,'SQLPath'
    ,@DirPathSSRS OUTPUT;
```

You will now find the Path to the ReportServer Logs as: 
    @DirPathSSRS + '\LogFiles'